# How FileInputStream read work?

Tags: java, fileinputstream

Someone please explain me how buffer array is filled in the following code:

```
try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        //(1) this print an empty string?
        System.out.println("1: " + new String(buffer));
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
        int len;

        while((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            //(2) this print text on my file?
            System.out.println("2: " + new String(buffer));
        }
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Update**: i have got useful info after reading following:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html

> Buffered input streams read data from a memory area known as a buffer; the native input API is called only when the buffer is empty. Similarly, buffered output streams write data to a buffer, and the native output API is called only when the buffer is full

Thanks all!

Comment: 1. Your array is `1024` `0`(s). 2. You've filled the buffer with `inputStream.read`

Comment: Do you really want to know **how** `read()` works internally to fill the array with values? Sounds like you need to learn more Java before diving in to such things, but if you do, look at the source code. It comes with the JDK, and any good IDE will help you see it, e.g. for Eclipse, press F3 when cursor is on `FileInputStream` and find the `read()` method.

Answer (score 2):

The `InputStream#read` method will read data from the input stream into the supplied buffer.

See the [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read-byte:A-) for details.

(In particular, see the return value – it will return -1 if there is no more data to read.)